# Why are my numbers not adding up when I win in my game?

Tags: java

In my game the computer has to generate 4 random colors.The user is then supposed to guess any of 4 colors in the options. If the user guesses one of the 3 computer generated colors right they get a point.I dont know why my points are not adding up.

MY CODE:

```
static String word,word2,word3;
    static int correct;
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //Intialize BufferReader
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Guess the blocks\n=================");
        System.out.println("Enter your first guess(R,G,B,Y):");
        String guess1=br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your second guess(R,G,B,Y):");
        String guess2=br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your third guess(R,G,B,Y):");
        String guess3=br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Your guess= "+guess1+guess2+guess3);
        int compcolor1=color1();
        int compcolor2=color2();
        int compcolor3=color3();
        computerColours( compcolor1,compcolor2,compcolor3);
        int letter=guess1.charAt(0);
        int letter2=guess2.charAt(0);
        int letter3=guess3.charAt(0);
        checkColoursCorrect(letter ,letter2,letter3, compcolor1,compcolor2,compcolor3);
    }
    public static int color1()
    {
         int randnum=(int) ((Math.random()*4)+1);
        return randnum;
    }
   public static int color2()
    {
        int randnum=(int) ((Math.random()*4)+1);
        return randnum;
    }
   public static int color3()
    {
        int randnum=(int) ((Math.random()*4)+1);
        return randnum;
    }
    static void computerColours(int compcolor1,int compcolor2,int compcolor3){

        if(compcolor1==1){
         word="R";

    }
         else if(compcolor1==2){
         word="G";
    }
         else if(compcolor1==3){
         word="B";
    }
         else if(compcolor1==4){
         word="Y";
    }

        if(compcolor2==1){
         word2="R";

    }
         else if(compcolor2==2){
         word2="G";
    }
         else if(compcolor2==3){
         word2="B";
    }
         else if(compcolor2==4){
         word2="Y";
    }

        if(compcolor3==1){
         word3="R";

    }
         else if(compcolor3==2){
         word3="G";
    }
         else if(compcolor3==3){
         word3="B";
    }
         else if(compcolor3==4){
         word3="Y";
    }
        System.out.println("Comp guess " +word+word2+word3);
    }
    static void checkColoursCorrect(int letter ,int letter2,int letter3,int compcolor1,int compcolor2,int compcolor3){
        if((letter==114||letter==82)&&(compcolor1==1)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter==71||letter==103)&&(compcolor1==2)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter==66||letter==98)&&(compcolor1==3)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter==89||letter==121)&&(compcolor1==4)){
         correct++;   
        }//guess1
        if((letter2==114||letter2==82)&&(compcolor2==1)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter2==71||letter2==103)&&(compcolor2==2)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter2==66||letter2==98)&&(compcolor2==3)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter2==89||letter2==121)&&(compcolor2==4)){
         correct++;   
        }//guess2
        if((letter3==114||letter3==82)&&(compcolor3==1)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter3==71||letter3==103)&&(compcolor3==2)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter3==66||letter3==98)&&(compcolor3==3)){
         correct++;   
        }
        if((letter3==89||letter3==121)&&(compcolor3==4)){
         correct++;   
        }

        System.out.println("Number of colours correct = "+correct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Identify a set of inputs that expose the problem, then single-step through your program with a debugger and see where it's doing something that you don't expect.

Comment: Your code was to lengthy to read it through. But maybe you made a mistake in your if-statements around the `correct++;` lines. Try to add `println' statements whether you ever enter these blocks. If not you made a mistake with the if statement.
Disable the random number generator and use simple zero for everything. It should be easy to check your statements for this case.

Comment: Your code is impossible to read; why did you switch to numerical constants in `checkColoursCorrect()`? `if (letter == 'R' || letter == 'r')` is much easier to read then `if (letter == 82 || letter == 114)`.

Comment: Your `color1()`, `color2()`, and `color3()` methods are identical. You can get rid of two of them.

Comment: @user3130732 your game and program is good. But the coding part is very bad. The way you are generating the random number after user enters the value makes impossible to test all the scenario. Also the logic to increase the score is not efficient. Please give me time time to come up with proper solution.

Comment: @user3130732 Get the working code from [here](http://pastebin.com/y2Kne8Rv)

Comment: This not a realy question, it's just spam.

Comment: Questions that dump a large amount of code and ask us to debug it for you are off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You for example check `if((letter==89||letter==121)&&(compcolor1==4))` but you never compare `compcolor1` with1 with `letter2` or `letter3`. Therefore, if compcolor1 = 'Y', and I type R Y G, then your code will fail to detect it, as you never compare compcolor1 with letter2.

To achieve what you want with your code you'd need to compare compcolor1 not only with letter, but also letter2 (which is compared only with compcolor2) and letter3 (which is compared only with compcolor3). So basically, compare all compcolors with all letters.

Few tips about writing cleaner code:

- there is absolutely no point in comparing char to decimal value, as it makes the code much harder to read. Note that `if(letter == 89)` gives exactly the same result as `if(letter = 'Y')` and the code is much clearer.
- if you compare your letter (or compcolor) to many constant values, you may change your series of if's into the switch statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html. This would also possibly add some clarity to your code.
- all of your `color` methods (color1, color2, color3) return a random int. You may just use one method `color` with the same logic as any one of the three you have. When you will assign int

  ```
      int compcolor1=color();
      int compcolor2=color();
      int compcolor3=color();
  ```

  every assignment will call color() seperately, so you get three random numbers anyway, and there is much less code = less places to make mistake and code easier to understand.

  - finally, when using if statements, look at this:

  > ```
  > if((letter2==114||letter2==82)&&(compcolor2==1)){
  >     correct++;   
  > }   //if letter is one of above, then the code below is 100% not true, so place an else:
  > else if((letter2==71||letter2==103)&&(compcolor2==2)){
  >     correct++;   
  > }
  > ```